# copy byte buffer contents to a structure

Tags: c#, c++, struct, buffer

I am trying to copy the contents of a buffer into a structure.The buffer contains a data received from a UDP recvfrom function.
In cpp I did it using memcpy function. How can I do that in C#?
I tried using Marshal function but there is some error.
My code is:

```
                    sending_socket.SendTo(buff2, sending_end_point);

                    sh = sending_socket1.ReceiveFrom(navdata, ref remote);
                    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(navdata));
                    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
                    try
                    {
                                    Marshal.Copy(navdata, 0, ptr, size);
                                    Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(navdata1));
                    }
                   finally
                    {
                                      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                    }
```

The name of structure is navdata1.
I have defined the buffer as: byte[] navdata = new byte[1024]
regards,
shiksha

Comment: Is `unsafe` code an option? "but there is some error." What error, ***exactly*** (i.e. copy/paste the error message)? What method were you using; `Marshal.PtrToStructure` ? or...?

Comment: Is the code correct? the navdata buffer is not being recognised...

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure from the info you have given, but it is possible that you are having "mapping problems". That is, your 'navdata' structure (which you haven't given the definition for) follows  C#/dot-NET conventions for data type sizes, alignment / position, etc, which are not what is actually sent "on-the-wire".

In C++ you were lucky that your compiler's conventions matched the actual data format (in C++ every, compiler/platform has its own conventions for this and it can be tweaked by compiler options, #pragmas, etc.)

If that is true, you can "manually" extract the data from the buffer, item by item. Actually, that is what you should do in general - though you can make some library for such purposes, to make your life easier.

Or you can use C++/CLI and maybe you'll get lucky (again).